# NullPointerException occurring with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, nullpointerexception, chess

I am making a 2-dimensional array in Java:

```
     import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class board {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame ("Chess");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setSize(600, 600);

        JButton tiles[][] = new JButton[8][8];
        tiles[0][0].setVisible(true);






    }

}
```

But when I run the program I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at board.main(board.java:9)

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

initialize the array

```
 static String boardL[][] = new String[5][5];
```

If you don't initialize an array, then it refers to `null`
You will get `NullPointerException` if you are trying to access the index without creating the array object.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized `boardL[][]` array.
initialize it as below,

```
static String boardL [][]=new String[10][10];
```

and then use it.

Answer (score 1):

The three thing you must do with arrays you must not forget it :

1. **Declaring**:  `int a[]`  this is how to declare an array.
2. **Initialization** : `a= new int[size]` this is how to initial arrays.
3. **Assignment** : `a [I] = 2` and assigning to something.

The first and second are very important, unless you must expect two kinds of errors :

- `NullPointerException`
- `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

The third is defaulted if you didn't assign it to any literal or a reference variable.

OR: You can combine the three steps in one step:

`int [] a = {1,4,65,39};`

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the array with a dimension (in this example 1):

```
boardL = new String[1][1];
```

If you want your array to have dimensions x by y:

```
boardL = new String[x][y];
```